# Removal of electronic silicone caulk sealant

Tags: controller, silicon

A controller is sitting under the sealant. I have tried to open it using hot air but no so successful. Can anyone please suggest me any solvent or easiest method to soften and remove the sealant.

[image: this is the controller size]

Comment: Have you tried any of the silicone caulk removers you'd find in a hardware store?

Comment: No, I haven't tried. What are the suitable ones which can make it soften or loosen or dissolve leaving the electronics safe enough?

Comment: shopping questions are not allowed here

Comment: It's not a shopping question to ask "what is an example of silicone caulk remover". Some terms like "builders putty" may seem clear to an expert, but for a novice they're not specific enough.